# how to fix Lumen migration error with vagrant box

Tags: laravel, lumen

I installed a fresh homestead vagrant box, then I installed laravel/lumen framework. When I try to run this command on my window machine "php artisan migrate" it gives me the error from my local machine.

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE
>      TABLE')

when I try to run the same command in a vagrant box inside my project directory it gives me no error.

Can someone please help me. I tried with Xampp as well but the same issue.

Comment: please make sure you have SQL driver installed on windows, if not, please check this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Comment: I think, installing homestead is useless, if I need to reinstall everything on the windows machine. I will try. anyway thanks

Comment: You should ssh into the box and run it? what is wrong with that approach